# Access array key inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to access an array key inside of an object in javascript.

Here is my .js file :

```
var contentData = [
            {
                tops: [
                            { image: "images/top1.jpg" },
                            { image: "images/top2.jpg" },
                            { image: "images/top3.jpg" },
                            { image: "images/top4.jpg" } ]
            }
    ];

$scope.objectArray = contentData;
$scope.objectCount = $scope.objectArray[0].length;
```

I am trying to access "tops" inside "contentData" to display the length of the "tops" array which should be four

Comment: Should be `$scope.objectArray[0].tops.length`

Answer (score 1):

```
> var contentData = [
...             {
...                 tops: [
...                             { image: "images/top1.jpg" },
...                             { image: "images/top2.jpg" },
...                             { image: "images/top3.jpg" },
...                             { image: "images/top4.jpg" } ]
...             }
...     ];
undefined
> 
> contentData[0].tops.length
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the `tops` property. It should be :

```
 $scope.objectArray[0].tops.length;
```